# WPF Listview changes style when adding gridview

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpftoolkit

I'm working on a project using the nuget package WPF material design ([also found here](https://github.com/ButchersBoy/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/tree/master/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf)).

I'm by no means very experienced in WPF templating and styling apart from the basics and I'm therefore not sure how this issue might be arising.
When using a ListView without a GridView for columns, the highlighting, text color etc. is how I want it. But when adding the GridView, it seems like the template is changing(?) and the ListView items colors are not how I want them.

Could I somehow maybe copy the template from the ListView and apply it to the GridView as well or am I completely wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can analyze the style templates or use a spy-tool to snoop which one is in effect - with VS 2017 you can also use the runtimedebugging to view details on wpf-elements in your window by using the live inspector, detect which ones are used in both cases and look through your resourcedicts. then create your own style mixing and matching what you like.

Spy-Tool I sometimes use: https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks a bunch, that seems very useful. I've managed to find the issue, though i'm not entirely sure it can be solved. When i use a gridview in my listview, i add classes as items and they are ordered in the columns. When i don't use the gridview, i simply add text as items.

In the snooper it shows, that clicking objects in the gridview calls a MouseDown on Border (Border), while clicking objects in the listview without gridview shows MouseDown on (Grid).
Do you have any tips for me?

Comment: You can restyle most appearances in WPF - but thats kindof dificult to do in comments. Mark question as answered if solved, create a new one wiht a minimal example code that shows what you have, what you want to get and ask how to get there - somenbody might be able to help you.